# Is there a way to export/import peers?

Tags: go-ethereum, peers, node-discovery

Every time I stop and re-start Geth, I wait for it to discover peers. Can I instead export my list of currently connected peers and use them as bootnodes in my next start? I know this list will act as a central peer database but still, more peers should mean more safety, right? I would really appreciate a code snippet for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

As i know there is not built in option to do so, however you could do it using a script : i am trying here to give you some response elements. the following snippet to output all the connected peers

```
admin.peers.forEach(function(value){console.log(value.id+"@"+value.network.remoteAddress)})
```

you need to write a script which read the outputs and use them as bootnodes

Comment: Great! Thanks. Maybe we need to write (or append) them to a file and read them later to construct the `--bootnodes` flag. I will try this and share if I succeed. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of geth, peers already contains `enode` then we can simply export peers by below javascript code snippet

```
admin.peers.forEach(function(value){console.log(value.enode)})
```